Wrong Version Android Sdk when building a relase - react native
when i run npx react-native build-android --mode=release to create a release version, it logs an error containing metro cache permission denied (the one inside temp) and when i run react-native doctor it gives this output
` ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

Versions found: 34.0.0, 35.0.0
Version supported: .b34.0.0`

I even did a reset to my windows and re installed everything as the docs specified.


I got frustrated up with all of the stages that aren't working online and simply clicked 'e'. It took its time and installed those mentioned missing packages.

I ran npx react-native doctor, and the problem was resolved.

Alternate you can try this also by installing Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) in  Android Studio > Tools > SDK Manager > SDK tools > Android SDK Command-line Tools.

Additional resources that may help:
https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2022/11/01/fix-react-native-doctor-android-errors/ https://developer.android.com/tools/


Note : this may consume some amount of bandwidth since it is re-downloading Android studio and all other dependencies(maybe everything should be about 2GB of data), and a strong internet connection is recommended.

good for u. doesnt work for me, react native doctor says the problem is fixed and when i run it again it outputs the same thing, i have android cl tools installed, ig the problem might have something to do with expo
